How can I prove by induction that $2^{2^n}>n^n $?
How can I prove that: $2^{2^n}>n^n$ for any $n\in \mathbb N$?
My trying: I tried to use induction, of course it worked to $n=1$.
Then  $n=k$, and $2^{2^k}>k^k.$ I assumed that as a true and tried to show that it implies in $n=k+1$ as a true.
I took: $ 2^{2^k}>k^k$.
$2^{2^{k+1}}>2^{2^k}k\geq2^kk^k=(2k)^k\geq(k+1)^k.$
My idea was to show that: $ 2^{2^k}k^k\ge(k+1)^{k+1},$ then using transitivity I could say that $2^{2^{k+1}}>(k+1)^{k+1}.$
But I couldn't demonstrate that $2^{2^k}k^k\ge(k+1)^{k+1}.$


"prove", not "proove". 2. Please make subject lines informative about the math content of your query.


Hint: $\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{k^k}\le(k+1)2^k$.

An easier path is taking logarithms: this reduces the problem to proving that $2^n\ln(2)>n\ln(n)$. For $n=1,2,3$ this inequality is trivial.
Now, notice that at the term $n+1$, the left expression is scaled by a factor of $2$. The right expression is scaled by a factor of $\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}$.
But, if $n\geq 3$, $$\dfrac{n+1}{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{n}\leq \dfrac{4}{3}$$
and $$\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)=\ln(1+1/n)\leq \ln(4/3)$$
so $$\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)}\leq 1+\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(n)}\leq 1+\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(3)}=\dfrac{\ln(4)}{\ln(3)}$$
Thus, the right factor gets scaled by a factor, at most, of $$\dfrac{4}{3}\cdot\dfrac{\ln(4)}{\ln(3)}<2$$
This implies that, if at the term $n$ the left expression is bigger than the right expression, this also happens for the term $n+1$.
Consequently, $2^n\ln(2)>n\ln(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and so $2^{2^n}>n^n$ is too.

For every $k\ge1$:$$(k+1)^{k+1}\le(k+1)(2k)^k$$
and by induction,
$$k+1\le2^{2^k-k},$$
the induction step being:
$$2^{2^{k+1}-(k+1)}-2^{2^k-k}=2^{2^k-k}\left(2^{2^k-1}-1\right)\ge1\cdot1.$$
Therefore,
$$(k+1)^{k+1}\le2^{2^k}k^k$$
